# Python Boto3 S3 Bucket Encryption result in 0 bytes file

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3, boto3, bucket

Needing some help here.

I have a Python script using Boto3 that does S3 Bucket encryption. It was working fine before this and just recently I noticed that when I use the script, it will cause the object to become 0 bytes.
It is working just fine if I were to encrypt it manually via the console.

Is anyone facing similar issue and would you mind to share any workaround? At least to recover back the files. I am clueless here.

I've did a quick troubleshooting and found out that when below line is executed, it will change the files to become 0 bytes.

```
client.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_key, ServerSideEncryption='AES256')
```

Thank you very much for your help and assistance.

Regards,
Ameer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line of code is missing a `Body` parameter. You aren't telling it what file or contents to upload.

Comment: looks like that is the root cause, let me try it out. do you know what is the best way to just change the object to be encrypted without using "put_object?' . Another question is, how can I retrieve back the missing file? I assume its gone missing now, since its 0 bytes

Comment: If you don't have versioning enabled on the bucket, then the file is gone. If you do have versioning enabled, then go look in the S3 console at the previous version. To change the file encryption you should be using a copy command instead of a put command.

Comment: Thank you so much Mark. it does make sense now. I've tried adding Body parameter and it works just fine. Weird because the script was working perfectly fine before this. Anyway, its good to follow best practices. Thanks again